# How to use javascript qodesmith / datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I had visited this site:

https://github.com/qodesmith/datepicker

I followed exactly (I guess) what he said on that site, but still not working. I get always the error Uncaught ReferenceError: datepicker is not defined. Here's my code:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento senza titolo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/datepicker.min.css">


<script type="text/javascript">
const picker = datepicker('#datePick', {

  // Customizations.
  formatter: (input, date, instance) => {
    // This will display the date as `1/1/2019`.
    input.value = date.toDateString()
  },

  // Settings.
  alwaysShow: true, // Never hide the calendar.
  dateSelected: new Date(), // Today is selected.
  maxDate: new Date(2099, 0, 1), // Jan 1st, 2099.
  minDate: new Date(2016, 5, 1), // June 1st, 2016.
  startDate: new Date(), // This month.
  showAllDates: true, // Numbers for leading & trailing days outside the current month will show.
})      


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="datePick"> 
    
    <script src="dist/datepicker.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

anyone have idea what is wrong with my code, please help

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have two scripts one is the external library and one is your usage of it, currently your script which uses the date picker is up in the header, if you move it to be below `<script src="dist/datepicker.min.js"></script>` it should work because by the time it gets excuted the datepicker variable will be defined

Answer (score 0):

As javascript runs scripts in order they are defined in your HTML document, your `script` block is executed before your library is loaded and hence you are seeing the issue.

Either load your library earlier (not a good practice unless you require it) or move your initialization script block right after you have defined library in `body` element.

Alternatively, you can attach `window.onload` event handler (recommended way) and in the event handler callback you should initialize your date picker.